# Eureka Client and spring integration

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I am trying to make my Spring application as Discovery Client. But the moment I add the following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.netflix.eureka</groupId>
        <artifactId>eureka-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.37</version>
    </dependency>
```

the GWT webapp fails to launch with 503 Service unavailable. Can netflix Eureka be used only with spring boot or spring cloud applications?

Comment: this is direct dependency to netflix eureka, not spring abstract of it, if you want to get any help you have to put more details - what did you set up, code fragments, exact exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  The moment I add the above dependency to my GWT application it fails to launch. But I am able to build the application (mvn clean install) and I do not see any exception other than 503 Service unavailable on browser ( Enabled all the log4j debugs ). I will try to see if I am missing something. one stupid question I have is, Can a Spring boot jar be included in a Spring application as a normal jar and will jetty or tomcat be able to load this jar?

Comment: @user1690436 Vanilla Eureka will work without spring-boot or spring-cloud, but then you'd have to refer to the eureka docs on how to get it running. It won't run in client side GWT either. More information will need to be provided for sure.  If you want to use spring cloud see https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples for some samples. The customers-stores, springbox-cloud and fortune-teller are all good starting points.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved:**

The version that I was using was very old. updated the version to 1.1.159 and everything is working fine.